# Tinymce UI issues and version

Tags: tinymce

I have just started with Tinymce and am trying to build rich text editor on my web page using self-hosted package. After integration, setting the Theme to Advanced and Plugin to autoresize, I see the editor as -
[Tinymce editor on web page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4L1FJ.png) (UI editor options looks distorted and not properly formatted)

I was expecting it to be something similar to what I see on Tinymce docs -
[Tinymce editor on docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83HHa.png)

Is this a Tinymce version specific or browser related issue? I tried downloading the latest version 5.8.2 (Development & Production), however the Themes I see are Silver & Mobile while it should be Simple & Advanced as I see in the official Tinymce documentations.

Also if I try to add multiple Plugins or Themes to my deployment as guided [here](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/general-configuration-guide/work-with-plugins/), it doesn't reflect on my web page.

These is how I have initialized my Tinymce -

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>

<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            if ($("#Test").length) {
                tinyMCE.init({
                    // General options
                    mode : "exact",
                    elements : "Test",
                    theme : "advanced",
                    width : 800,
                    plugins : "autoresize",
                    content_style: " div, p { font-size: 14px; }"
                });
            }
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using version 3 of TinyMCE (9+ years old). Upgrade to version 5 and it should be a lot better.